# Enable Analytical Storage Time to Live via CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to create a collection in Cosmos DB API for MongoDB using the CLI and enable the Analytical Storage Time to Live option with "On (no default)" but the documentation regarding this process (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb/mongodb/collection?view=azure-cli-latest#az_cosmosdb_mongodb_collection_create) don't provide any example or valid values that is possible to enter to configure as below:

[image]

Does anyone know how to execute the CLI to have the same effect as the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable the Analytical Storage Time to Live option with "On (no default)" you need to use -1 value, like:

--analytical-storage-ttl -1

If you put a value > 0, it will enable "On" option and sets the seconds of lifetime.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore (2023). It's not in the doco and the CLI complains if you try and provide this